# How to disable steam-link host display during streaming?

Tags: steam-in-home-streaming, steam-link

When I use my Steam Link, the game is displayed on my host pc too.
It takes a lot of resources and I don't see it so it's completely useless.
So I would like to know how I can display the game **only** on my Steam Link client?

Comment: It doesn't take extra resources to stream to both screens, I doubt you'd get any gains by not displaying it on screen.

Comment: @CommandoAir While it takes no extra resources, it could be useful to keep the PC screen available for other tasks.

Answer (score 3):

As [CommandoAir](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/173570/commandoair) says, thereis no point in that. Your PC is rendering the game only once, and then Steam streams that video to your Steam Link. It doesn't take any "Extra resource". If you want it off, you can turn off your screen.